# $v$-adic ring of integers of a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field and $v$ a finite valuation of
>   $K$. We can consider the completion $K_v$, which is a finite extension
>   of $\mathbb{Q}_v$.
>
> We can define a "$v$-adic ring of integers" by $$\mathcal{O}_v=\{x\in
>  K_v : P_{\text{min},K_v/\mathbb{Q}_v, x}\in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]\}.$$ The
>   "regular" ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is of
>   course contained in $$\mathcal{O}':=K\cap\left(\bigcap
>  \mathcal{O}_v\right).$$ Does the other inclusion hold (i.e.
>   $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}'$) ?

Being given that an element of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ that belongs to $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ for all $p$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, I think that this is true, but I did not succeed in formalizing this.

Indeed, if $x\in \mathcal{O}'$, we only have the relationship $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]\ni P_{\text{min},K_v/\mathbb{Q}_v,x}\mid P_{\text{min},K/\mathbb{Q},x}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p[X]$, so we could not say that for example $P_{\text{min},K/\mathbb{Q},x}\in\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$.

Comment: I think the following argument works: It is enough to show that for $x\in K$, if $|x|_v\in\mathcal{O}_v$ for all $v$ finite, then $x\in\mathcal{O}$. It is true for $K=\mathbb{Q}$, using Ostrowski and the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is factorial. For a general number field, use Ostrowski and the fact that $\mathcal{O}$ is a Dedekind domain.

Comment: It literally sounds like you're saying that $x\in K$ such that $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)\geqslant 0$ for all places $\mathfrak{p}$ must be in $\mathcal{O}_K$. But, isn't this obvious? :S

Comment: Now it is, indeed! But I didn't know that Ostrowski's theorem could be generalized to number fields. Knowing that $v=v_\mathcal{P}$ for some prime ideal makes things obvious.

Comment: Ah, I see :) You should post this as an answer to your (own) question! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the answer is yes. The key is that by the generalization of Ostrowski's theorem for number fields, we have $$v=v_\mathfrak{P}$$  for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$. But it is obvious that an element $x\in K$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if $$v_\mathfrak{P}(x)\ge 0$$
for all $\mathfrak{P}\in\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$.